Does the Earth's Magnetic Field Affect Sleeping Position?
Does the Earth's magnetic field affect the sleeping position of a person? For sleep experience with Nature sounds, check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FzjrdiUr90

No, no it doesn’t.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics

There seems no direct link between magnetic field and the human body.
A short period exposure to strong magnetic field is harmless (MRI)
